# How to extract weekend from a time period in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the a time interval between two time points in hourly based (calculate working hours for employees). For instance,

Start Time 4/11/2014 9:00
End Time   5/11/2014 10:00

For this case, the result should be **9** hours (since the time slot for employee is **09:00-13:00,14:00-18:00, 8** hours each day).

However, I would like **remove the weekend hours** from my time interval. For example,

Start Time        31/10/2014 9:00

End Time          3/11/2014 10:00

In this case, the answer should be **9** hours as well, since **Nov 1st and 2nd are Sat and Sun** respectively.

How could I achieve this goal  using R programming. Sincerely thanks for reply.

1. 4/11/2014 9:00
   4/11/2014 10:00
   expected result: 1
2. 4/11/2014 9:00
   4/11/2014 15:00 expected result: 5
3. 4/11/2014 9:00
   4/11/2014 18:00 expected result: 8
4. 4/11/2014 9:00
   5/11/2014 10:00 expected result: 9
5. 31/10/2014 9:00
   3/11/2014 10:00 expected result: 9

Comment: Thanks,this is just an example, the format is day/month/year. I want to extract a time interval between these time points, for this case, the result should be 9 hours (since the time slot for employee is 09:00-13:00,14:00-18:00, 8 hours each day). However, I don't know how to "remove" weekend in my calculation. I should use the word "remove" instead of "extract", sorry for that.

Comment: Could you show an example that mimics your original dataset, ie. 10-12 lines of data. and the expected result.

Comment: Sorry it's my first time using stackoverflow, I edited my question and please kindly refer to it. I have data.frame with to columns and their name is Start.Time and End.Time respectively